ES1371 driver gets recognized tho it doesn't play
i am making an ES1371 driver, vmware detects it and gives it as a valid driver tho no audio plays, i've been struggling with it for about two days and still nothing, does anybody know what is wrong with it
IOPort.Write32(BAR0 + 0x04, 2);
transferBuffer.ReadSample(0, Buffer);
IOPort.Write32(BAR0 + 0x14, 0x00020000);
IOPort.Write32(BAR0 + 0x14, 0x00180000);
IOPort.Write32(BAR0 + 0x10, 0xeb403800);
SetPlayback2SampleRate(44100);
IOPort.Write32(BAR0 + 0x0c, 0x0c);
IOPort.Write32(BAR0 + 0x38, (uint)Buffer);
IOPort.Write32(BAR0 + 0x3c, 4096);
IOPort.Write32(BAR0 + 0x28, 0x7FFF);
IOPort.Write32(BAR0 + 0x20, 0x0020020C);
IOPort.Write32(BAR0 + 0x00, 0x00000020);
IOPort.Write32(BAR0 + 0x20, IOPort.Read32(BAR0 + 0x20) & 0xFFFFFDFF);

i am expecting audio to play
